# Kafka cluster + what is the right way to recover Kafka cluster when one machine is down

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka cluster version 1.0 with 3 Kafka nodes ,

the situation now is about one Kafka that shutdown due HW machine problem , and from `topic describe` we can see that "`-1`" appears on some topic partitions , and `-1` means that no leader

example:

```
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1000,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 1    Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1001,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 2    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1000    Isr: 1002,1000
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 3    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 4    Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1002,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 5    Leader: -1      Replicas: 1001,1000,1002    Isr: 1001
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 6    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1000,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 7    Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1001,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 8    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1000    Isr: 1002,1000
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 9    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 10   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1002,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 11   Leader: -1      Replicas: 1001,1000,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 12   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1000,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 13   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1001,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 14   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 15   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 16   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1002,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 17   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1001,1000,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 18   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1000,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 19   Leader: -1      Replicas: 1000,1001,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 20   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 21   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 22   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1002,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 23   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1001,1000,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 24   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1000,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 25   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1001,1002    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 26   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1000    Isr: 1002,1000
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 27   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1000    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 28   Leader: 1000    Replicas: 1000,1002,1001    Isr: 1000,1002
    Topic: topic_moner_givec_toc    Partition: 29   Leader: -1      Replicas: 1001,1000,1002    Isr: 1001
```

based on above details when one machine is down , and the other 2 kafka broker are up

what is the right approach in order to set the leader "`-1`" to right broker id instead of "-1"

one option is of course is to restart the broker service , but we want to avoid broker restart

pleas note that our Kafka version is very old - 1.0 version

and The brokers does not support ELECT_LEADERS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to recover it is to run `kafka-server-start` after addressing whatever server error occurred (hardware failure, network failure, power outage, etc)

In other words, the broker is already offline. You're required to restart it if you want it back

Comment: for now we cant start the broker with HW problem and this can takes weeks , so my question is base on , so dose restart the other 2 brokers can be consider as solution in spite I am looking for other solutions and not only restart the other 2 brokers that still up

Comment: You'll need to run kafka-reassign-partitions command to change the leader to an active, in sync replica. Restarting the others will cause data loss

Comment: unfortunately  the situation is that - we runs  before 1H the reassign-partitions process on kafka01 for each topic , but  the missing leader as "1" still remained

Comment: That command only tells Zookeeper where partition replicas should exist, not the leader, actually. Also, if your only ISR value is 1001, then there's no replicas that can be used to take over leadership, anyway. So, even if reassigned to `[1000,1002]`, then using preferred leader election tool, you'll lose data from each of those partitions. Your only other option is a restart for id 1001, as answered. Or, you can setup a whole new, empty broker with `broker.id=1001` and trick Zookeeper into thinking it's the old one

Answer (score 1):

From your picture, broker `1001` is down and you have no other Insync replica (ISR) for those partitions, so you are stuck without a new leader.

One solution is to accept dataloss, and set `unclean.leader.election.enable=true`. That way, either one of the remaining brokers can become leader for those partitions and you can progress. However, any messages on `1001` but not on the other 2 brokers will be loss after you recover `1001`

Comment: you said "One solution" , can yo described the other solutions?

Comment: The other solution is to wait until you can repair `1001` and bring it back.